# YUI Compressor dropping semicolons in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yui-compressor

I'm using the following line to create a comrpessed version of a js with yuicompressor:

java -jar /home2/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar --type js /home/site/libs/javascript/photos_functions.js >/home/site/libs/javascript/photos_functions-min.js

But for some reason, yui seems to be mis placing semicolons (;) all over the place. I've only started noticing it. It appears to be an occurance after using a jquery ajax function $ajax({});

What it seems to do is remove the semicolon, then add it to the next } (weird).

Anyone else seen this or no a way/option to fix it?

**Example Before:**

```
function photo_load_vs_breakdown(photo_id,page) {

    display_white_box('photo_vs_box');

    url =  SITEURL + "/libs/ajax/vs_mode_breakdown.php";
    params = 'photo_id='+photo_id+'&page='+page;



    $.ajax({ 
        url: url,
        cache:false, 
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            if(page == 0){
                $('#photo_vs_box_contents').html(data.content);
            }
            else{

                newpage = page + 1;
                $('#vs_mode_wins').append(data.wins_append);
                $('#vs_mode_losses').append(data.lose_append);
                $('#vs_load_more').attr('onclick','photo_load_vs_breakdown('+photo_id+','+newpage+')');
                if(data.disable_vs_load_more == 'yes'){
                    $('#vs_load_more').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }

            }

        }
    }); 
}
```

**Example After:**

```
function photo_load_vs_breakdown(a,b){display_white_box("photo_vs_box");url=SITEURL+"/libs/ajax/vs_mode_breakdown.php";params="photo_id="+a+"&page="+b;$.ajax({url:url,cache:false,type:"POST",data:params,dataType:"json",success:function(c){if(b==0){$("#photo_vs_box_contents").html(c.content)}else{newpage=b+1;$("#vs_mode_wins").append(c.wins_append);$("#vs_mode_losses").append(c.lose_append);$("#vs_load_more").attr("onclick","photo_load_vs_breakdown("+a+","+newpage+")");if(c.disable_vs_load_more=="yes"){$("#vs_load_more").attr("disabled","disabled")}}}})};
```

Notice the location of the semi colon on the end.

Comment: Can you post a code example - before and after the compression?

Comment: @rsp I have added an example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the YUI compressor seems to be doing here is not exactly misplacing or moving your semicolon but actually dropping the semicolons after the last expression in functions, **and** adding a single semicolon to the end of your code (to avoid problems when you concatenate two or more scripts together).

For example this code:

```
function x() { a(); b(); c(); }
function y() { a(); b(); c(); }
```

would get compressed to this code:

```
function x(){a();b();c()}function y(){a();b();c()};
```

Note that every last semicolon was removed in both functions but only one semicolon after the second function was added.

See the [Online JavaScript/CSS Compression Using YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) for some quick experiments. Also compare it with [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl//uglifyjs), another tool for JavaScript minification, which for this example outputs:

```
function x(){a(),b(),c()}function y(){a(),b(),c()}
```

See: [UglifyJS readme](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/#readme) for more options. (There is also a more advanced [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#readme) being developed.)

Answer (score 1):

YUI Compressor, just like many other code transformation tools, doesn't really "edit" your code by deleting or moving parts of it. Actually it compiles it to some intermediate form with all your style and other meaningless bits completely removed and then regenerates new code according to its own internal rules. There's no way to somehow "preserve" symbols that are essentially no-op - such as whitespace, extra brackets, extra semicolons, etc because they're simply not saved anywhere.